# Google Charts: Aumentar el tamaño del bocadillo de los Valores

Tags: php, web, aplicación-web, google-chart-api

Estoy haciendo una web que contiene graficos de google chart, y a la hora de clicar en una línea para ver su valor, si el nombre de ese valor es muy largo, se solapa con el valor en sí.

No sé mucho de js, me las he arreglado hasta ahora abreviando  los nombres.

[image: 1]

Comment: una "solución" temporal, sería añadir un espacio en el nombre de calefacción